# data isn't being inserted into database. not sure what i'm doing wrong

Tags: php, mysql

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$zipcode = $_POST["zipcode"]; 
$country = $_POST["country"];
$month = $_POST["month"];
$day = $_POST["day"]; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO birthdays (name, address, city, state, zipcode, country, month, day)
VALUES ($_POST["name"], $_POST["address"], $_POST["city"], $_POST["state"], $_POST["zipcode"], $_POST["country"], $_POST["month"], $_POST["day"])";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "You have been added to the birthday list";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

does the database prefix need to be included in the login/database? i'm confused right now.

`sacrmfuw_sjay` is with the prefix.. `sjay` is without it

Comment: format your code... You also need to add more information - I have no idea how you connect. If your question is "Do I need to use the prefix" then my question is "why don't you just try it"?

Comment: Your variables aren't quoted. If you query did work, you'd be wide open for SQL injection. You're using mysqli, so take advantage of prepared statements and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), and get rid of those pesky quoting issues.

Comment: You should be getting syntax errors. The `"` for your `POST` values are closing and opening your `$sql` encapsulation. Those values also would need to be quoted to insert. Look at the colors and you should see the issue. You wont get to the `mysqli` error because your PHP never parses. Check your error logs. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'`-https://3v4l.org/OiUpU

Comment: Other dupes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: OK, let's start slow and work towards a solution. First, you set variables, but you don't use them in your query. You can use this edit to clean things up:

$sql = "INSERT INTO birthdays (name, address, city, state, zipcode, country, month, day)
VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$country', '$month', '$day')";

Answer (score 2):

If we are going to include literal values into our SQL text, it is imperative that any potentially unsafe values be properly escaped.  The `mysqli_real_escape_string` function is custom written to do that for us.

To create SQL text that includes literal values, we could do something like this:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO birthdays (name, address, city, state, zipcode, country, month, day)"
  . " VALUES"
  . " ('" . $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST["name"]    ) . "'"
  . ", '" . $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST["address"] ) . "'"
  . ", '" . $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST["city"]    ) . "'"
  . ", '" . $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST["state"]   ) . "'"
  . ", '" . $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST["zipcode"] ) . "'"
  . ", '" . $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST["country"] ) . "'"
  . ", '" . $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST["month"]   ) . "'"
  . ", '" . $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST["day"]     ) . "'"
  . ")";
```

The `mysqli_real_escape_string` function is used for *values* being included in the statement. If any of the *identifiers* (column names, table name) are MySQL Reserved Words, those also need to be properly escaped typically by enclosing the identifier in backtick characters.

---

The preferred pattern, as an alternative to including literal values in the SQL text, is to use *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*. A static SQL statement like this:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO birthdays (name, address, city, state, zipcode, country, month, day)"
  . " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Then prepare the SQL text into a statement, and *bind_param* the values to the statement, and then execute the statement.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: got it solved.. 

from this 
`$sql = "INSERT INTO birthdays (name, address, city, state, zipcode, country, month, day)
VALUES ($_POST["name"], $_POST["address"], $_POST["city"], $_POST["state"], $_POST["zipcode"], $_POST["country"], $_POST["month"], $_POST["day"])";`

to this

`$sql = "INSERT INTO sacrmfuw_birthdays.birthdays (name, address, city, state, zipcode, country, month, day)
VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$country', '$month', '$day')";`

Comment: @JayS: That pattern appears to be *vulnerable* to SQL Injection. Consider what will happen when $city is "`O'Fallon`", or $name is "`D'Onofrio`"... or something more nefarious, like [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) Don't go down the path of adopting coding patterns that are vulnerable to SQL Injection, when it's *not that hard* to adopt patterns that are *not* vulnerable https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @JayS: Spencer is correct. You should never, ever, ever, EVER do it that way. Very bad form. In addition to `bind_param()` (the link in this answer), you should read about `real_escape_string()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php